# grails remoteFunction onComplete, passing an event?  Bug?

Tags: grails

Per the [remoteFunction documentation](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html) one can cause a javascript function to be called when the remoteFunction finishes, using the onComplete parameter.   From examples I've seen on the web, one can supply a function with an event parameter, i.e.

```
 onComplete: 'finishUp(e)'
```

Then I found this is broken in 1.3.6, per Grails bugs filed, [here](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7052) and [here](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7062), which was supposed to be fixed for 1.3.7 (perhaps 1.3.6), per the bug resolutions.

However, this is still broken in my 1.3.7.  Are you able to get this to work?  Is there a bug in my syntax.  Note if I drop the 'e', I get the function to be called (can tell by an alert).  But, if I add in the "e", the function doesn't get called.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onComplete: 'finishUp'
```

And see if it calls the function and if the event object is present in

```
function finishUp(e) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks Gregg, I tried that and had to do a 'finishUp()' to get the function to be called.  My "alert("got finishUp, event: " +e)" indicated that "..., event: undefined".  So that still doesn't appear to send the event in.